# Varnish Does not work

Tags: varnish

I installed varnish as well on my server , but the performance did not change , The http://www.webpagetest.org/ says caching system does not enable on your server , i'm using default configuration of varnish , it's my header :

```
status: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache  
X-Powered-By:   PHP/5.3.29  
P3P:    CP="NOI ADM DEV PSAi COM NAV OUR OTRo STP IND DEM"  
Expires:    Mon, 1 Jan 2001 00:00:00 GMT    
Cache-Control:  no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0  
Pragma: no-cache    
Set-Cookie: 73ab794b527721e09d2124da5815cf79=2f8ca1fed15724e75f5bf3824a26a9cd; path=/; HttpOnly 
Last-Modified:  Thu, 25 Sep 2014 08:28:53 GMT   
Content-Type:   text/html; charset=utf-8    
Content-Length: 77965   
Accept-Ranges:  bytes   
Date:   Thu, 25 Sep 2014 08:28:53 GMT   
X-Varnish:  1531877383  
Age:    0   
Via:    1.1 varnish 
Connection: close
```

Answer (score 3):

I will see if i can help for any future views of this issue, There are a number of things that will cause Varnish not to cache content. You will need to work through all of them and hopefully have a good logging / metrics setup so you can identify which pages / resources are not responding from cache.

Your cache control headers were:

```
status: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache  
X-Powered-By:   PHP/5.3.29  
P3P:    CP="NOI ADM DEV PSAi COM NAV OUR OTRo STP IND DEM"  
Expires:    Mon, 1 Jan 2001 00:00:00 GMT    
Cache-Control:  no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0  
Pragma: no-cache    
Set-Cookie: 73ab794b527721e09d2124da5815cf79=2f8ca1fed15724e75f5bf3824a26a9cd; path=/; HttpOnly 
Last-Modified:  Thu, 25 Sep 2014 08:28:53 GMT   
Content-Type:   text/html; charset=utf-8    
Content-Length: 77965   
Accept-Ranges:  bytes   
Date:   Thu, 25 Sep 2014 08:28:53 GMT   
X-Varnish:  1531877383  
Age:    0   
Via:    1.1 varnish 
Connection: close
```

To have this particular request cachable you need to fix:

- `Expires:    Mon, 1 Jan 2001 00:00:00 GMT`

  This tells Varnish not to cache
- `Cache-Control:  no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0,
  pre-check=0`

  This tells Varnish not to cache (Varnish 4+, Varnish 3 will still cache this)
- `Set-Cookie: 73ab794b527721e09d2124da5815cf79=2f8ca1fed15724e75f5bf3824a26a9cd; path=/; HttpOnly`

  Varnish will not cache any response with Set-Cookie

In order to tackle metrics / logging so that you can get visibility of all requests i have written about Varnish setup options: https://www.section.io/varnish-install-quick-and-detailed/

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

> Cache-Control:  no-store, no-cache ...

Basically:

- next lookup fails (Varnish will not store the response in cache)
- browsers will not cache the response so any F5 will request the resource again from your server.

Use the below in your VCL

```
sub vcl_fetch {  

remove beresp.http.Cache-Control;

  set beresp.http.Cache-Control = "public";

}
```

Comment: I added this code to my config , but my website performance did not changed and webpagetest.org still showing the level F of caching

Comment: The response that your application is returning specifies that it should not be cached. Make sure that you return the public cache headers.

Comment: yes,i see publish cache in my headers after applying your code :) , but my performance did not changed yet

Comment: i think i need to  adding another configuration , but i don't know what should i do

Comment: You need to discard backend set-cookie as well. Check https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/3.0/tutorial/cookies.html

Comment: how can i testing varnish working as well?

Comment: Check here http://www.isvarnishworking.com/

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem on ubuntu server with PHP-FPM:

```
Expires:    Mon, 1 Jan 2001 00:00:00 GMT    
Cache-Control:  no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0  
Pragma: no-cache
```

Problem was session.cache_limiter in `/etc/php/7.1/fpm/php.ini` (PHP-FPM)

```
sed -i "s/session.cache_limiter = nocache/session.cache_limiter = ''/" /etc/php/7.1/fpm/php.ini
```

Other problem to resolve was "SetCookie" for testing use this:

```
vcl 4.0;

backend default {
    .host = "127.0.0.1";
    .port = "8181";
}

sub vcl_recv {
    unset req.http.cookie;
    return(hash);
}

sub vcl_backend_response {
    unset beresp.http.set-cookie;
    set beresp.ttl = 30m;
}

sub vcl_deliver {
}
```

One more thing that I was missing was "`a2enmod proxy_http`" for ProxyPass in Apache2